# Why does pip not install the latest CMake on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, python, pip, cmake

As you can see on https://pypi.org/project/cmake/, this is not the latest version. On Windows, it's work as expected. Is it a bug or something?

```
root@85acafdb63d3 /app# pip3 install cmake
Collecting cmake
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/3a/6d2c6bc7fb8eaf79bdc9d6d8647f54f83d22bf973552d5af5f2c86e89e8a/cmake-3.13.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.9MB 60kB/s 
Installing collected packages: cmake
Successfully installed cmake-3.13.3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Nope, it's because the default pip version is old. lead to cmake installed a old version.

Comment: Yes, I meant the repository version of `pip`, not `cmake`. BTW, you haven’t specified your Ubuntu or pip version.

Comment: I post the env info on the github issue link. Sorry for missing it here.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the default pip version is old, see https://github.com/scikit-build/cmake-python-distributions/issues/88.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! While this answer gives a hint of what to do, it would be better if you [edit]ed it to contain actual instructions to check the version of pip and upgrade it.